# The fractal dimension of the complementary space

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fractals, fractal-analysis

I'm a physicist who specializes in studying the behavior of granular materials. Research has confirmed that certain distributions of granular sizes exhibit fractal characteristics. In simpler terms, the number of particles larger than a particular size 'd' follows a specific power-law relationship, with the exponent referred to as the fractal dimension.

I'm currently investigating a related aspect of these granular materials: the spaces between the particles, known as pores. As this space is the complementary space of the grains inside a constant volume, I'm curious to know if the size distribution of these pores also displays fractal properties similar to the distribution of the grain sizes.
My question to the mathematicians is this: if a fraction of a fixed volume is a fractal, does the complementary space also exhibit fractal behavior ? If so, is the fractal dimension of the complementary space comparable to that of the initial space?
I’m sorry if my question is not well formulated.

Comment: This sounds more like a physics question.

Comment: Is there a question here? Because it seemed like you were stating what you are interested in, rather than how someone here can help you.

Comment: I want to know if the size distribution of pores is also a fractal and if its fractal dimension is similar to that of the grain size distribution.

Comment: In that case I agree with the comment made by @JohnDouma. Perhaps a more suitable place for this sort of question is the Physics stack exchange forum.

Comment: The answer to the math part of this question is negative. As an example, take the ternary Cantor set. It's complement in the real line is not fractal.